# Ubuntu Server Background color

Tags: command-line, server

How is the server background color changed? Not using the desktop version. Have been able to customize the bash command line, but not the overall background color.

Thanks

From the answers i am assuming there is no simple way of accomplishing this, such as editing a file. The setterm only highlights the command line with a color but doesnt really change the background as a whole.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding here. If you for example use SSH to connect to a server, there's no graphical GUI, only a text-based one. Basically, there are no images sent back and forth, only text. So, the server essentially does not *have* a background color. To change the background color you see, you'd have to look into the settings of your terminal, terminal emulator etc.

Comment: Thanks for verifying, wanted to changed the background on the server itself, not really to an image, but another solid color.

Comment: I think there's still some misunderstanding. There *is* no background color on the server. The only thing that's transmitted between your client and the server is the raw text, not some image displaying the text. How that raw text is displayed on the client side, is the responsibility of whatever terminal/terminal emulation/... you're using. So you'd need to look into the settings of your client-side program.

Comment: Believe we are stating the same thing. I'm asking about the physical server on the rack, not connecting through a client, there is not a built in feature to change the default black, correct?

Comment: There can't be a feature to change something that doesn't exist ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setterm` command:

```
setterm -term linux -back <background_colour> -force <text_color> -clear
```

From the colors, you can chose from (both force-and background):

> Black|blue|green|cyan|red|megenta|yellow|white|default|

Fore more options:

```
setterm -help
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Looks like changing the background is not a built in feature.